# Issue in addPlugInSingleRowFunction upgrading Esper version from 5.3 to 8.3

Tags: java, complex-event-processing, esper

In our existing application we are using Esper Version 5.3.
We have added few addPlugInSingleRowFunction() to use it in EPL as below --

final Configuration cepConfiguration = new Configuration();
cepConfiguration.addPlugInSingleRowFunction("toNumber", Double.class.getName(), "parseDouble");
cepConfiguration.addPlugInSingleRowFunction("toBoolean", Boolean.class.getName(), "parseBoolean");

This was working fine in 5.3 version.

Post upgrading to 8.3 above code changed as per Esper documentation --

cepConfiguration.getCompiler().addPlugInSingleRowFunction("toNumber", Double.class.getName(), "parseDouble");
cepConfiguration.getCompiler().addPlugInSingleRowFunction("toBoolean", Boolean.class.getName(), "parseBoolean");

But once the sendEventBean() method is called to send a Event to runtime we are seeing below exception every time.

Surprisingly events are getting matched as per the statements present in runtime even if below exception are coming. Though we are not sure whether some events are not matching or not.

Can someone please help on this?

`applog.cls=com.espertech.esper.common.internal.epl.expression.dot.core.ExprDotNodeForgeStaticMethodEval,applog.mthd=staticMethodEvalHandleInvocationException,applog.line=228,applog.msg=Invocation exception when invoking method 'parseDouble' of class 'java.lang.Double' passing parameters [null] for statement 'stmt-0': NullPointerException : null,exc.stack=java.lang.NullPointerException\n\tat sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:1838)\n\tat sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.parseDouble(FloatingDecimal.java:110)\n\tat java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:538)\n\tat generated.StatementAIFactoryProvider_a4bd241445010f45474e4598e34521ca1b2836db_stmt450.m8(StatementAIFactoryProvider_a4bd241445010f45474e4598e34521ca1b2836db_stmt450.java:161)\n\tat generated.StatementAIFactoryProvider_a4bd241445010f45474e4598e34521ca1b2836db_stmt450$2.get(ANONYMOUS.java:148)\n\tat com.espertech.esper.runtime.internal.filtersvcimpl.FilterParamIndexEquals.matchEvent(FilterParamIndexEquals.java:32)\n\tat com.espertech.esper.runtime.internal.filtersvcimpl.FilterHandleSetNode.matchEvent(FilterHandleSetNode.java:100)\n\tat com.espertech.esper.runtime.internal.filtersvcimpl.EventTypeIndex.matchType(EventTypeIndex.java:178)\n\tat com.espertech.esper.runtime.internal.filtersvcimpl.EventTypeIndex.matchEvent(EventTypeIndex.java:124)\n\tat com.espertech.esper.runtime.internal.filtersvcimpl.FilterServiceBase.retryableMatchEvent(FilterServiceBase.java:179)\n\tat com.espertech.esper.runtime.internal.filtersvcimpl.FilterServiceBase.evaluateInternal(FilterServiceBase.java:96)\n\tat com.espertech.esper.runtime.internal.filtersvcimpl.FilterServiceLockCoarse.evaluate(FilterServiceLockCoarse.java:52)\n\tat com.espertech.esper.runtime.internal.kernel.service.EPEventServiceImpl.processMatches(EPEventServiceImpl.java:610)\n\tat com.espertech.esper.runtime.internal.kernel.service.EPEventServiceImpl.processWrappedEvent(EPEventServiceImpl.java:450)\n\tat com.espertech.esper.runtime.internal.kernel.thread.InboundUnitSendEvent.run(InboundUnitSendEvent.java:43)\n\tat java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)\n\tat java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)\n\tat java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)`

Answer (score 0):

You could turn on compiler logging (config.getCompiler().getLogging().setEnableCode(true);) and make sure you have INFO level logging. You can inspect "StatementAIFactoryProvider_a4bd241445010f45474e4598e34521ca1b2836db_stmt450.m8" at line 161 to see what the problem is. Sounds like a null value gets passed to Double.parseDouble. But since I don't have the complete code its hard to say.